# Android studio preview pane not rendering ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

I'm running the latest version of android studio ,Problem is the preview pane does not render the ActionBar when any of the AppCompat themes are used, if i change the theme of the preview pane it works fine(Not change actual theme) ,but is there any discepency in doing this,

my *styles.xml* is as follows

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

when the preview pane is set to AppTheme ,the ActionBar ain't shown ,however it works fine in my device and AVD,

[image: No Action Bar shown]

As you can see this makes it  hard to debug and test the  ActionBar

Please suggest some fix to this and how exactly does a AppCompat theme differ from an ordinary one?,I'm just an android beginner .

Thanks!

Comment: @JaredBurrows ,Thanks for the info ,but I did not create the bounty

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=78944

Unfortunately it is low priority.

Update: set the preview to API 22

Comment: Is it really? Because I'm noticing a possible side effect: when I select a NoActionBar theme from the Preview tools, it still has an action bar.

Comment: It was fixed with minor issues in platform tools 22

Comment: Weird. I definitely have platform tools 22. I'm not setting any Activity context in xmlns:tools. The ActionBar is there, my ToolBar goes below it even if I chose Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar from the preview pane.

Unrelated, but just to be clear: I just extend Activity (because I'm using Flow), and my AppTheme is also Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.

Comment: Read the link. There is still isuues in some configurations

Answer (score 1):

In my styles.xml I had

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

had to change it to just

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score -1):

There is culprit in your MainActivity(which ever your activity)  when your are using app.compact.v7 your are supposed to extend **ActionBarActivity** instead Activity

Comment: I'm sorry i don't really understand ,my Main Activity and fragment do extend ActionBarActivity and moreover i said it works fine on the device etc,only the preview pane is messed up.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h57QpXp2TRg    watch this video you can understand

Comment: Question is about preview and not runtime appearance .